# How to position right element with offset based on left element

Tags: swift, snapkit

It is simple.

I want to make this using SnapKit:

```
leftElement   rightElement
anotherleftElement   rightElement
lftElmnt   rightElement
```

It means that every rightElement have margin based on width of leftElement plus lets say 20 px. I use it as a cell in a TableView.

Left element has constraints like this:

```
leftElement.snp.makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
            make.top.equalTo(self).offset(10)
            make.left.equalTo(self).offset(20)
            make.right.equalTo(self).offset(-20)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You also have to add contraints to the `rightElement` and connect the `rightElement`'s left constraint to the `leftElement`'s right constraint (plus offset):

```
leftElement.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
   make.top.equalTo(10)
   make.left.equalTo(20)
   make.bottom.equalTo(-10)
}
rightElement.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
   make.top.bottom.equalTo(leftElement)
   make.left.equalTo(leftElement.snp.right).offset(20)
   make.right.lessThanOrEqualTo(20)
}
```

Comment: Sadly this dont work. The element is not visible at all.